# What could be the plural of "Pidgey"?

Tags: grammatical-number

As you maybe know, Pokémon Go was released could of days ago. I have been asking couple of question on gaming.se and [my last one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273241/are-all-eggs-to-worth-to-hatch) required me to use the plural of "Pidgey" which is the name of a Pokémon.

Assuming that it is not an irregular noun, what could be his plural? I want to know because of what rule, as English is not my first language and I want to be able to handle my question by myself for the next time.

Comment: A peculiarity of Pokémon is that all its creatures' names are the same in both singular a plural. *A pack of Slowking are migrating.* *Aren't those Lumineon beautiful?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about correct usage for an arbitrarily imposed and non-mainstream convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plural of Pidgey will be Pidgey itself. We can say, I saw 2 Pidgey. Some people may say "I say 2 Pidgey's" but the correct sentence is "I saw 2 Pidgey".

Comment: _Pidgey’s_ could never be the plural. It's the possessive singular. The morphological plural would either be _Pidgeys_ or _Pidgies_.

Comment: @Janus That's assuming that normal rules apply here. With such non-standard usages, it's fairly pointless insisting that standard / normal rules must apply. For instance, the pure plurals ex's and do's are licensed by some authorities, so Go's (to avoid the possibly even less acceptable-looking Gos) is not impossible. Here, apparently, the zero plural is dictated by the company (though doubtless if they used _Pidgey'''s_ it would have to be considered 'acceptable').

Comment: @Edwin That’s assuming _Pidgey_ is non-standard. I don’t see any reason it should be. It’s a perfectly cromulent, English-sounding name that in no way violates English phonotactics or sounds ‘foreign’. No reason to treat it as anything but a regular noun. _Do’s_ and _Go’s_ are both in that limbo territory of monosyllabics that end in a long vowel written with a single letter, where a simple _-s_ ends up being misleading, which is why pluralising them with an apostrophe is licensed. I’ve never seen _ex’s_ licenced by any authority and would seriously question such licence; could you link one?

Comment: @Janus It ***is*** non-standard, with zero plural, as imposed by the Pokemon people. There is a pub with the name "The Aberrant Apostrophe's" or suchlike. These questions are really off-topic as not real English. //  I'm still looking for a source for ex's = exes; I know I found one (but the article may now have been revised).

Comment: @Edwin Yes, with the ‘singular plural’, it is definitely non-standard. I meant that if it were to be pluralised regularly, by adding /z/, I would see no reason why its plural should be orthographically non-standard. (I would guess that the vast majority of speakers are not aware that Pokémon characters are dictated to be the same in the plural as in the singular—I certainly wasn’t—and would just pluralise them regularly.)

Comment: @Janus [UsingEnglish.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/87284-Sean-s-guide-to-the-apostrophe) has: << The apostrophe is not used to mark plurality, apart from cases like capital S’s or number 1’s, being clearer than Ss or 1s, even though this would normally denote possession by the S or 1; similarly dot your i's and cross your t's, grade A’s or yes’s, no’s, do’s and ex’s. Apostrophes can further be used to clarify the endings of unusual words, such as n'th rather than nth. >> Mind you, I find fault with pronouncements from H & P, and 'Sean' isn't exactly the Grammar Czar.

Comment: ... I'm fairly sure I've seen ex's as a pure plural option in a dictionary, but it might been listed only during a narrow time-span, between _ex_ appearing as an allowable word for ex-partner and the general accepting that _exes_ is the better form. Perhaps the usage arose as X's is probably the more favoured plural for the letter, and 'ex' is 'the name of the letter'.